# How to sort a std:list when you need member data?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

So I would know how to sort it if I could use a vector but we are required to implement it using a list.  Our professor said that we can use the sort function already implemented in the list class.  If it was a vector I could create a struct and then use sort from < algorithm > to go though my list but it won't let me use that since std::list doesn't have random access.  The API says "template< class Compare >" but I don't think that will help me.

I understand that I could use the sort function but I need to use member data to sort it.  I'm sorting Points by their polar angle and I need to use the current Point that is a member of my class as the "origin" so I can't use a static sorting comparator like I normally would.

EDIT
I'm using this as my sorting call:
`sortedList.sort(sorting);`

and here is my function:

```
bool sorting(const Point& p, const Point& q) {
    Point z = pointStack.top();
    Point u = Point(p.getX() - z.getX(), p.getY() - z.getY());
    Point v = Point(q.getX() - z.getX(), q.getY() - z.getY());
    double r = u.polarAngle();
    double s = v.polarAngle();
    if (r < s) {
            return true;
    } else { 
            return false;
    }
}
```

I keep getting

> c:\users\wooly\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\proj5\proj5\grahamscan.cpp(20): error C3867: 'GrahamScan::sorting': function call missing argument list; use '&GrahamScan::sorting' to create a pointer to member

since I need the top value of pointStack to do the sorting but its a member of my class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call the sort function directly if your value type has operator< defined.

```
std::list<int> myList;
// Do stuff to the list
myList.sort();
```

Or if it doesn't you need to provide a functor that will do the comparison.

```
struct MyClassComparator {
    bool operator()(const MyClass& first, const MyClass& second) const {
        // Return true if first should go before second
        return true;
    }
};

std::list<MyClass> myList;
// Do stuff to the list
myList.sort(MyClassComparator());
```

Comment: So I'm kind of new at structs.  Would I make that a subclass of my current class so that it could access the current Point and then have the overloaded () take in two Points?

Comment: @woolcock66 no, it doesn't need to be a subclass of anything. It's called a functor.

Comment: It is common to make it its own struct. Remember that the only difference between C++ classes and structs is that everything in structs is public by default. However, if your comparator class is separate from your user defined type then you can only compare using public members and methods unless you declare the comparator as a friend to your class. 

If this is confusing then you can always define an operator< in your class and let the no parameter version of sort() do the work.

Comment: okay I edited my original post to have my current attempt at sorting it.

Comment: What is in your list? Using your current function you can only sort a container of Point objects and pointStack has to be globally available so that the function can access it.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to create a struct that took in a Point argument.  Then I could just pass it the Point at the top of the stack and everything works fine.  Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `sort` member function if the types you are storing can be compared with `<` already:

```
list<int> l;
l.push_back(3);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(1);

l.sort();

print_list(l);
```

And if `print_list` printed the list, it would print `1 2 3`.

You only need to pass `sort` an argument if the type you are storing in the list doesn't have `operator<` defined. You can do that like this:

```
class Compare_MyClass {
public:
    bool operator()(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
        return lhs.member < rhs.member; // or some comparison
    }
};

list<MyClass> l;
l.push_back(MyClass(...));
l.push_back(MyClass(...));
l.push_back(MyClass(...));

l.sort(Compare_MyClass());
```